# Mysql Error 1064 when trying to save changes in text editor

Tags: php, mysql, editor, mysql-error-1064

I'm running this [website](http://hyperfixer.com).

I get a mysql error 1064 when i'm saving changes in my (wysiwyg) text editor

here is the first error

> Database error: Invalid SQL: UPDATE page_master SET page_title =
>   'Help', page_content = '
>
> MySQL Error: 1064 (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 's bid online. We do charge tradesmen a small fee
>   for each quote they send. Howev' at line 1) Session halted.

and here is the second error

> Database error: Invalid SQL: UPDATE page_master SET page_title =
>   'Terms and Conditions and use', page_content = '
>
> MySQL Error: 1064 (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 's web site is available only to individuals who
>   can form legally binding contrac' at line 1) Session halted.

Here is my sql table.

http://pastebin.com/F15P91TM

Comment: It'd be nice if you could add the relevant part of the code in your question. It's hard to scroll through 1600 lines of code to find the error.

Comment: It seems that you have non-masked quotes in your text you're trying to insert

Comment: As the error is at `'s bid online. We do charge tradesmen a small fee for each quote they send. Howev` or to point it more obviously at `'` I would say you don't escape special chars, could this be?

Comment: @Amal Murali The relevant part of the code is in the post i just posted, at the Database error: Invalid SQL:....... error, in phpmyadmin it would be pointing to the page_master table, that contains the page_title which is pointing to the page_content table that contains the text that the text editor is supposed to input.

Comment: @bish wow i've checked, the editor always stopped working the moment the first " 's " string appeared, ahhh so thats why he used hyperfixer FAQ•s instead of hyperfixer FAQ's! It's confirmed, the moment i type ''' into the text editor mysql freezes. Please you've got to help me fix this. ( - -)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you confirmed my comment above you have to escape the string you want to store in your database.

There just use the `real_escape_string` function, see manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

If you are still using the deprecated `mysql_*`-functions, you have to use: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-escape-string.php. But again, the use of `mysql_*` is deprecated and should not be used anymore!

Comment: Thanks mysql_real_escape_string finally worked after figuring out how to use it after a long time ( > _ <) real_escape_string doesn't work.